# Getting sequence of td when button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have made a table with one button in each td and 4 td in each tr, I want to get the sequence of the td when the corresponding button is pressed, but I am getting sequence 0-4 because parent changes after next row. Is there a way to get the sequence of buttons from 0-11. here is my jQuery code.

```
$('.act-butn').on('click', function() {
        var btnClicked = $(this).parent().index();
        $('.activity1').text(btnClicked); 
});
```

and here is my Table

```
<table class="beta" width=443 id="logButtons">
  <center>
    <tr>
      <td><input type='button' name='Production' value='Production' id="actB1" class="act-butn" /></td>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Break' value='Break' id="actB2" class="act-butn" /></td>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Medical' value='Medical' class="act-butn" /></td>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Comfort Break' value='Comfort Break' class="act-butn" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Meeting' value='Meeting' class="act-butn" /></td>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Training' value='Training' class="act-butn" /></td>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Business Improvement' value='Bus. Improvement' class="act-butn" /></td>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Idle' value='Idle' class="act-butn" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Downtime' value='Downtime' class="act-butn" /></td>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Follow up' value='Follow up' class="act-butn" /></td>
      <td> <input type='button' name='one-to-one' value='one to one' class="act-butn" /></td>
      <td> <input type='button' name='Coaching' value='Coaching' class="act-butn" /></td>
    </tr>
  </center>
</table>
```

Please suggest changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the `<input>` index you need a collection of all those inputs to index against

```
var $inputs = $('.act-butn').on('click', function() {
     // index of `this` in `$inputs` collection
     var btnClicked = $inputs.index(this);
     $('.activity1').text(btnClicked); 
});
```

Or if you want `<td>` index within all `<td>` based on input clicked:

```
var $td = $('.act-butn').on('click', function() {         
     var btnClicked = $td.index( $(this).parent() );
     $('.activity1').text(btnClicked); 
}).parent();
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ob2ysswx/)**</kbd>